# How to assert that a entry exist in the HashMap instead of separately asserting using containKey() and containValue()

Tags: java

I got a Hashmap parsed from the XML document and wanted to check if a list/set of entries exist.

```
hashMap.entrySet() -> returns set of entry and I want to assert "key1":"value1" exist in this set.
```

How can this be done?
Reference from stack overflow show containsKey and containsValue but not containsEntry.

References:
[Search if specified key and value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289394/search-if-specified-key-and-value-exists)

Comment: Just `"value1".equals(hashMap.get("key1"))`

Answer (score 0):

An Entry is nothing more then the Key and the Value associated with it.
So if you want to check if an specfic Key has an Specific Value associated with it just do this:

```
SomeObject actualValue = map.get(key)
if(!expectedValue.equals(actualValue))
{
   //Key has other Value associated with it
}
else
{
    //Key has the expected Value
}
```

Comment: And, of course, as long as your map is not expected to contain null values, then you can dispense with any prior call to `containsKey(key)` and just check that the return from `get(key)` is not null -- which is implicit in your answer, but I just wanted to call it out for the OP.